# openstreetmap: check if a latlong is outside polygon(region)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

i have created a region(polygon) on **openstreetmap** and I want to check if my current lat-long is inside that polygon or not. I am using **leafletjs**. here is my link -> http://imaker.asia/leaflet/area.html

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No need to use anyother than https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet api . Just use polygon.getBounds().contains(e.latlng) function

Comment: Sorry to tackle the simplicity of this answer but… `polygon.getBounds()` gives you the containing rectangle. So if your polygon is smaller than this rectangle (e.g. it is a triangle), there are areas where the bounds contain the point, but not the polygon… To be more explicit, if the polygon were a disk, the bounds contain the 4 corners of the containing rectangle (square in that case), but obviously the disk does not contain them.

Comment: @ghybs ok you sound logically correct. if that function doesnt work in all the cases then what is the perfect solution?

Comment: @BhaumikBelani Unfortunately you have to use the exact polygon shape (i.e. from all its vertices) to compute whether your point is within or not. That is exactly what Leaflet-PIP and Turf.js are doing. Use Turf.js if you need more functionalities, or Leaflet-PIP if that is the only extra functionality you need.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Leaflet-PIP](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip) library (Point In Polygon) should give you the feature you are looking for.

```js
var gjLayer = L.geoJson(statesData);
var results = leafletPip.pointInLayer([-88, 38], gjLayer);
// results is an array of L.Polygon objects containing that point
```

Then simply check if your polygon is within the result array or not.

Note that the first argument can be either an `L.LatLng` object (e.g. using `myMarker.getLatLng()`), or an array of coordinates, but **it must be in the order `[Lng, Lat]`**, on the contrary of Leaflet's usual `[Lat, Lng]`.

The second argument must be a GeoJSON group layer.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to leaflet-pip is [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/). It offers a lot more spatial functions, but has no tight integration with Leaflet (requires the developer handle coordinates directly)