# Get all markers in polygon in leaflet draw

Tags: javascript, leaflet, polygon

How can I get all markers in polygons leaflet `draw` ?

Create markers:

```
for (let i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {

    var point = addressPoints[i];
    var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(point["lat"], point["lng"]))
    .on('click', onClickMarker);

    markers.addLayer(marker);
}
```

And draw polygon created

```
map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {
    var layer = e.layer;
    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
    var polygon = layer.getLatLngs();
    console.log(polygon);
});
```

I want to get all markers on `polygon`

Answer (score 2):

You would want to create an empty array and push all elements that are are an instance of `L.Marker` and are within bounds of the polygon.

```
map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {
  let layer = e.layer;
  drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
  let polygon = layer.getLatLngs();
  console.log(polygon);

  let markers = [];

  map.eachLayer((layer) => {
    if(layer instanceof L.Marker && map.getBounds().contains(polygon)) {
        markers.push(layer.feature);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your dranwItems a Leaflet GeoJSON Layer Group and use Turfjs or Leaflet point-in-polygon on each Marker to know if it is within one of the drawn layers, as explained in [openstreetmap: check if a latlong is outside polygon(region)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693790/openstreetmap-check-if-a-latlong-is-outside-polygonregion/35694439?r=SearchResults#35694439)